# Where is the graphics card driver fot NVIDIA GEFORCE 610M on ubuntu 10.10?

Tags: 10.10, drivers, nvidia, graphics

The graphics card of my notebook is NVIDIA GEFORCE 610M.

I installed ubuntu 10.10.

I installed NVIDIA-Linus-x86_64-295.33.run, but it seems not support NVIDIA GEFORCE 610M.

Which driver should I use to support my grapics card properly?

Thank you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I install a graphics or wireless card driver?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/47506/how-do-i-install-a-graphics-or-wireless-card-driver)

Answer (score 1):

Additional Drivers will auto-detect the drivers needed for your hardware and give you an option to install them.  Launch it from System->Administration->Additional Drivers.
[image: screenshot]

Comment: I have tried "System->Administration->Additional Drivers",but none of any drivers appear. What to do next?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the link to the correct download(considering you have a 64bit system)

http://www.nvidia.com/object/linux-display-amd64-295.20-driver.html